# Calculating $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}z\,\Theta\left(\frac{h}{2}-|z|\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Calculate
> $$ \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}z \, \Theta\left(\frac{h}{2}-|z|\right), $$
> where $\Theta$ is the Heaviside function.

I know that

$$ \Theta\left(\frac{h}{2}-|z|\right) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{for $|z|\leq \frac{h}{2}$, and} \\[0.333em]
0 & \text{for $|z|> \frac{h}{2}$.}
\end{cases} $$

So I would calculate:

$$ \int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}z \, \Theta\left(\frac{h}{2}-|z|\right)
= \int \limits_{-\frac{h}{2}}^{\frac{h}{2}} \mathrm{d}z
= h $$

Comment: Your solution seems correct, modulo the assumption $h\geq 0$. For $h<0$, the integral is identically zero (although I am not sure if this condition is realized in any of the physical context considered).